# merge second half of rows for each id but rows are not same for each id

Tags: python, pandas

[attached the data image please go through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNLYY.png)I have a data frame containing 2 columns one is 'id' and another one is 'text'. Each row contains one id and its text in 2 different columns. Now, I want to merge the second half of text rows for each id doing a group by on id.

```
    id      text
0   AB001   hello this is samrey how may I assist you
1   AB001   thank you for contacting chat helpline
2   AB001   could you please tell me your problem
3   AB002   Thank you for contacting ou team
4   AB002   agent will be assigned to you shortly
5   AB003   I will reset the the handset
6   AB003   switch off and switch on
7   AB003   still not working
8   AB003   it should work
9   AB003   now its working thanks a lot
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide input data, expected output

Comment: yeah sure please give me a moment

Comment: I want to merge second half of text rows for each id.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "merge second half". Describing what you are expecting would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the strings,

```
new_df = df.groupby('id').text.apply(' '.join).reset_index()


    id      text
0   AB001   hello this is samrey how may I assist you tha...
1   AB002   Thank you for contacting ou team agent will b...
2   AB003   I will reset the the handset switch off and s...
```

Edit: Based on the comment, "suppose an id has 6 lines we have to join last 3 lines for that particular id". The following will capture the second half of the rows and join them. If there are 3 rows in an id, this will join last 2.

```
df.groupby('id').text.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x[(len(x)//2):])).reset_index()


    id      text
0   AB001   thank you for contacting chat helpline could you please tell me your problem
1   AB002   agent will be assigned to you shortly
2   AB003   still not working it should work now its working thanks a lot
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but please note that I have to join only the second half of the lines by grouping the id.

Comment: What do you mean by only second half of the lines?

Comment: Do you mean first and the last line of each id?

Comment: No, here is the deal. we can easily join all the text rows by grouping the id but I want to join the second half of text rows for each id. For suppose an id has 6 lines we have to join last 3 lines for that particular id and next the following id has 20 text lines second half of text rows should be joined for that particular id.

Comment: df.groupby('id').text.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x[(len(x)//2):])).reset_index()
this worked for me thanks alot.

Comment: how do I project the other columns also in the output if i have few other columns?

Comment: Merge text from other columns into the original or to a new one?

Comment: how do i consider only first five lines and join in one row grouping it by id?

Comment: You can first select first 5 rows and use rest of the same code; df.iloc[:5, :].groupby('id').text.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x[(len(x)//2):])).reset_index()

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply